# Change Stock Status and update Stock Amount

Tags: stock, quantity, stock-status

We have gotten an API from our manufacturer, now we want to enable stock in these products and give them the right quantity...

We use this code:

```
$_product->setData('use_config_manage_stock', 0);
$_product->setData('manage_stock', 1); // should be 1 to make something   out of stock
$_product->setData('is_in_stock', 1); // is 0 or 1
$_product->setData('qty', 1234);

try {
    $_product->save();
    echo "done." . PHP_EOL;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "{$e}";
}
```

But for some reason, stock wont be enabled on these products and the quantity is also not applied... Whats wrong with this code?!

this is how the products are normal and even after the script it stays like that
http://puu.sh/di3RT/f9ecfc32ce.png

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
$_stockItem = $_product->getStockItem();
$_stockItem->setData('use_config_manage_stock', 0);
$_stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 1); // should be 1 to make something   out of stock
$_stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 1); // is 0 or 1
$_stockItem->setData('qty', 1234);

try {
    $_product->save();
    echo "done." . PHP_EOL;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "{$e}";
}
```

Comment: i get `...Call to a member function setData() on null in...` on the first `stockItem->setData`

Comment: This is strange. it means that `$_product->getStockItem();` returns null. This shouldn't happen.

Comment: Still not working....